# How to stop Office 2010 updates in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010

Had Office 2010 installed, then upgraded to Windows 10 and got Office 2016. How do  I stop updates to Office 2010? I already uninstalled it but it still updates.

[Excel 2010 updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AU2cE.png)

Comment: How did you determine it is till updating? Can you upload a screenshot?

Comment: Yep. Just added it in the link for a recent Ecel 2010 update I got

Comment: Double check for Office runtimes which might be installed, or excel viewer etc

Answer (score 0):

In the Windows *Update settings* CPL, select *Advanced options*. Uncheck *Give me updates for other Microsoft products...*.

[image: Updates Advance settings]

Comment: This just stops updates to Office 2016, in reality, the author wants Office 2010 back (I think)

Comment: " I already uninstalled it but it still updates." implies he has 2010 back.

Comment: No I don't. I uninstalled 2010 because I have 2016 now but I'm still getting updates for 2010 after the uninstallation.

Comment: Sadly, this seems to be the only solution that works. You won't be getting updates for any other Microsoft products either.